# Browse button that will display image file from a local directory folder in html

Tags: html, browser, preview

Hi I wanted to know if its possible to create a button in html that functions like a "Browse" button like when clicked it will show the computer directory such as the Local Drive, Documents etc.

What I wanted to do is use this "Browse" button to set a Folder path that has Images (.png/.jpeg) then once directory folder has been selected the image file name should show up in a list form.

*Note: The machine is connected on a LAN network everything is shared and with 
       out any restriction.

**Sample**

**Path:** 
C:\Documents\TargetFolder (this is what will be browsed using the "Browse" button the path location may change could be from a different location within the same machine or different computer over the same network that is why a "Browse" button is needed)

**Output:** 
From the Source(TargetFolder) lets say with 20 image file a list should show up with the image file name, path properties(created date and time )and the actual image pulled up. Switches as well base on what was selected on the list

*Is this possible?*

[browse button window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeWEK.jpg)

[webpage looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Nvm.jpg)

Comment: Browsers have restriction on local file access, that how browsers are made. This is due to security issues.

Comment: Some browsers offer extensions such as Chrome's https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-image-file-viewer/lhlckkgdiojkapplglfeomlkjllphilo

Answer (score 0):

What you want actually is a file manager (file gallery to be more precise) in web browser.

there is no such thing in that would help you get that without writing hundreds of lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

and also follow the below code

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var preview = document.querySelector('.preview');

input.style.opacity = 0;input.addEventListener('change', updateImageDisplay);function updateImageDisplay() {
  while(preview.firstChild) {
    preview.removeChild(preview.firstChild);
  }

  var curFiles = input.files;
  if(curFiles.length === 0) {
    var para = document.createElement('p');
    para.textContent = 'No files currently selected for upload';
    preview.appendChild(para);
  } else {
    var list = document.createElement('ol');
    preview.appendChild(list);
    for(var i = 0; i < curFiles.length; i++) {
      var listItem = document.createElement('li');
      var para = document.createElement('p');
      if(validFileType(curFiles[i])) {
        para.textContent = 'File name ' + curFiles[i].name + ', file size ' + returnFileSize(curFiles[i].size) + '.';
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(curFiles[i]);

        listItem.appendChild(image);
        listItem.appendChild(para);

      } else {
        para.textContent = 'File name ' + curFiles[i].name + ': Not a valid file type. Update your selection.';
        listItem.appendChild(para);
      }

      list.appendChild(listItem);
    }
  }
}var fileTypes = [
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/pjpeg',
  'image/png'
]

function validFileType(file) {
  for(var i = 0; i < fileTypes.length; i++) {
    if(file.type === fileTypes[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}function returnFileSize(number) {
  if(number < 1024) {
    return number + 'bytes';
  } else if(number >= 1024 && number < 1048576) {
    return (number/1024).toFixed(1) + 'KB';
  } else if(number >= 1048576) {
    return (number/1048576).toFixed(1) + 'MB';
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

form {
  width: 600px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

form ol {
  padding-left: 0;
}

form li, div > p {
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

form img {
  height: 64px;
  order: 1;
}

form p {
  line-height: 32px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

form label, form button {
  background-color: #7F9CCB;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px ridge black;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  height: auto;
}

form label:hover, form button:hover {
  background-color: #2D5BA3;
  color: white;
}

form label:active, form button:active {
  background-color: #0D3F8F;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>
    <label for="image_uploads">Choose images to upload (PNG, JPG)</label>
    <input type="file" id="image_uploads" name="image_uploads" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" multiple>
  </div>
  <div class="preview">
    <p>No files currently selected for upload</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry buddy but the question was to get to folder an that will load only 20 of its image items. This make him to upload files for him

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but (if it works for your use-case), the user could select multiple files from the same directory using the browse button.

There is a lovely example on MDN

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#example_showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images

```html
<input type="file" id="input" multiple>
```

```js
const inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
function handleFiles() {
  const fileList = this.files; /* now you can work with the file list */
}
```

```js
function handleFiles(files) {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files[i];

    if (!file.type.startsWith('image/')){ continue }

    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = file;
    preview.appendChild(img); // Assuming that "preview" is the div output where the content will be displayed.

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```